# Angularjs change views on window resize

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm busy with Angularjs application and everything is fine, but I have problem with implementing mobile version of site. I can't just do responsive styles, I need to use different view files for mobile/desktop version. So, in my app I use ui-router with following config:

```
dopGruz
    .config([ '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider','$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state('root',{
            views: {
                "navbar" : {
                    controller: 'viewsController',
                    templateProvider: function($http, viewsWatcherFactory) {
                        return viewsWatcherFactory
                            .get('app/views/nav-bar.html')
                            .then(function(obj){
                                return $http
                                    .get(obj.templateName)
                                    .then(function(tpl){
                                        return tpl.data;
                                    });
                            });
                } },
                "" : { template: '<div ui-view></div>' }
            }
        })
```

My factory which return mobile template based on window width

```
dopGruz.factory('viewsWatcherFactory', [
    '$http',
    '$timeout',
    function($http, $timeout) {

        var _ifMobile = (function(){
            return window.innerWidth < 850;
        })();

        return {
            get : function(id) {
                return $timeout(function(){
                    var path = id;
                    if (_ifMobile) {
                        path = id.split('/');
                        path.splice(path.length-1,0,'mobile');
                    }
                    if (Array.isArray(path)) {
                        path = path.join('/');
                    }
                    return {templateName : path};
                }, 0);
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

This works well on page load - if window width < 850px - it actually loads mobile version of template. But is there a way to call templateProvider manually based on event? I have a controller, in which I would like to implement it:

```
dopGruz.controller('viewsController', function ($scope,$window) {

    angular.element($window).bind('resize', function() {
        console.log($window.innerWidth);
        // do some magic and call templateProvider and update views files.
        $scope.$digest();
    });

});
```

Perhaps there is a more simple and right way to do it. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use ng-include and set the src attribute to a scope variable that points to either the mobile or desktop version of the template.  I didn't take this all the way but you should get the idea by this sample.

Controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.templates =
[ { name: 'mobile.html', url: 'mobile.html'},
  { name: 'desktop.html', url: 'desktop.html'} ];
$scope.template = $scope.templates[0];
});
```

Main template:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <ng-include class="col-md-12" src="template.url"></ng-include>
</body>
```

Mobile template:

```
<div>mobile template</div>
```

Desktop template:

```
<div>desktop template</div>
```